# Mac Automator to check screen colors

Tags: automator

Is there a way Mac Automator can check screen color at a certain pixel?

I have googled this problem and the only thing I found is by using applescript to take a screenshoot. (Which is not sufficient as it’ll save me a photo everytime it excutes. :|

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution may work for you. Using terms from the (FREE) [AppleScript Toolbox scripting addition](https://astoolbox.wordpress.com/), to set your mouse location and click at that specified coordinate...  You can save this following code I just wrote, in AppleScript editor as an application.

```
set xyCoordinates to {}

activate
set temp to words of text returned of (display dialog ¬
    "Please Enter Your X And Y Coordinates" default answer ¬
    "250, 250" buttons {"Cancel", "OK"} ¬
    default button 2 ¬
    cancel button 1 ¬
    with title "Get RGB Color Value") as list

repeat with i from 1 to count of temp
    set thisItem to item i of temp
    set end of xyCoordinates to thisItem as integer
end repeat

set theIcon to path to resource "AppIcons.icns" in bundle application "Digital Color Meter"

activate application "Digital Color Meter"
delay 1
AST set mouse point location xyCoordinates
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Digital Color Meter"
    set resultUIElementList to click at xyCoordinates
    delay 1
    keystroke "C" using {shift down, command down}
end tell
delay 1
set colorValue to words of (the clipboard) as list
delay 1

activate
display dialog ("Your RGB Values Are " & return & (item 1 of colorValue) & " " & (item 2 of colorValue) & " " & (item 3 of colorValue)) ¬
    buttons {"OK"} default button "OK" with icon theIcon giving up after 5
quit application "Digital Color Meter"
```

[image]

Comment: Expected end of line, etc. but found “set” for this line: AST set mouse point location xyCoordinates

Comment: Ah okay I did not read your comments! really big thanks its working awesomely!